# How can I set specific dates on my x axis using FixedLocator?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to set specific dates for my x-axis tick locations. But my x-axis  object type is `datetime64[ns]`. These are my attempts with the error code.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"date": ["2022-01-01", "2022-01-02", "2022-01-03", "2022-01-04"],
                   "sales": [100, 200, 300, 400]})
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])

ax = sns.lineplot(data=df, x="date", y="sales")

# First attempt with pd.Series object.
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(FixedLocator(df["date"][::2]))

# Tried converting to np.array.
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(FixedLocator(df["date"][::2].values))

# Tried converting to list.
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(FixedLocator(df["date"][::2].to_list()))
```

This is the error shown.

```
UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'multiply' cannot use operands with types dtype('<M8[ns]') and dtype('float64')
```

Is there any way around it? Or is there other ways I can set specific dates (from a `list` or `pd.Series`) on my x-axis?

Answer (score 0):

This will do.

```
ax.set_xticks(df["date"][::2])
```

Comment: or `ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(FixedLocator(matplotlib.dates.date2num(df["date"][::2])))`

Comment: Please provide an explanation of your code, so that others can understand why it works.